# SharePoint 2013: Search Suggestion working only on enterprise search site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have created a site collection which has an enterprise search as well. Only the search box on the homepage of enterprise search shows search suggestions where as no other site or sub-site shows.

What could be the reason for it and how to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled the Search Suggestion according to [this Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721441.aspx), it should work for everybody.
Make Sure Prepare query Suggestions timer job completed successfully, if not then run the below power-shell and then test it.

```
Start-SPTimerJob -Identity "prepare query suggestions"
```

Another Suggestion is, turn off the suggestions, then turn on & run the timer job, now test it.

Comment: Didn't help. I had already tried all this

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions have an "owner" scope, if the scope is not the SSA it will not show up everywhere.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: I have checked by Get-SPEnterpriseSearchOwner -Level SSA and it returns some values whereas for other levels it throws exception. Can you PLEASE guide me to the right direction

Comment: Troubleshoot this by determining if the Suggestion you seek is in the scope of your site. You can use PowerShell to change the scope if needed.